# Compute $\mathbb P\{X_2-X_1<1/4, W_1+X_2<1/2\}$ where $X_i\sim Unif[0,1]$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2$ two independents and uniform r.v. on $[0,1]$. Compute
$$\mathbb P\left\{X_2-X_1<\frac{1}{4}, X_1+X_2<\frac{1}{2}\right\}.$$

For me, if $Y=X_2-X_1$ and $Z=X_1+X_2$, then
$$\mathbb P\left\{X_2-X_1<\frac{1}{4}, X_1+X_2<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\iint_{(-\infty ,\frac{1}{4}]\times (-\infty ,\frac{1}{2}]}f_{Y,Z}(y,z)dydz,$$
but I can't really compute $f_{Y,Z}$. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :** First of all, one can prove that $$f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=f_{X_1,X_2}(h(y,z))\det J_h(y,z)$$
where $h=g^{-1}$ and $(Y,Z)=g(X_1,X_2)=(X_2-X_1,X_1+X_2)$. So you can indeed continue from your idea and conclude.

**Method 2 :** You can also remark that 
$$\mathbb P\{X_2-X_1<1/4, X_1+X_2<1/2\}=\mathbb P\{X_2-1/4<X_1<1/2-X_2\}=\iint\limits_{\{(x_1,x_2)\in [0,1]^2\mid x_2-1/4<x_1<1/2-x_2\}}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2.$$

Comment: you may could mention that $f_{X_1,X_2} \equiv 1_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}$

Comment: @Gono: I hope the OP knows that :)